# "Application not installed" on Android 2.3.5 based Videocon Mobile Devices-APK

Tags: installation, apk, 2.3.3-gingerbread

I am trying to install non market applications on Videocon mobile, i am getting the "Application Not installed" Done . Even I enabled access for non-market apps in the settings. But rest of all the mobiles APK is installing and working fine. Please help me to get over this.

Comment: (1) Has the app been installed before? (2) Do you have enough storage space on your phone? Also, what phone?

Answer (score 0):

If the application has been downloaded previously, and the certificates doesn't match, android will display the same error. Make sure you have uninstalled any previous versions of the application and then reinstall the application. If you can't find your application in the app drawer, you should go into setting->Application Manager and then uninstall the application.

Or the second reason may be that the app is not compatible with your android version.

Answer (score 0):

Your mobile did not support the version of apk file installed. You can reduce the SDK version editing with APK Easy editior tool. Some files will work if you having luck. Package installer to be upgraded mainly. no one ready to implement of old andriod versions of mobile so you throw it and buy new android mobile which was supporting all apps